# Laravel Snappy PDF rotation nowrap text issue

Tags: php, css, laravel, laravel-snappy

Here is the css style

```
<style>
#rotatetext {
      float:center;
      text-align:center;
      -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
      -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
      -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
      transform: rotate(-90deg);
      filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
      vertical-align: middle;
}
<style>
```

here is the code in the blade file

```
@foreach ( $subj_list as $subj_code )
<th id="rotatetext" style="text-align: center; text-wrap: nowrap;">Q{{ $q_key }} {{ $subj_code }}</th>
@endforeach
```

This is the output my problem is text-wrap wont work, I want todo is a 1 line for every subject code to remove the extra spaces.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SPOM6.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already fixed my problem here the updated css code is here.

```
#rotatetext {
      float: center;
      -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
      -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
      -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
      transform: rotate(-90deg);
      filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
      vertical-align: middle;
      white-space: nowrap !important;
      position: relative; 
      bottom: -50;
}
```

I used the white-space: nowrap; so the text will never be wrap, and I also used the position to match the height of the text in the table header. here is the image of the solved issue.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/rAmIX.png